# How get some status for first "n" number of rows for particular where condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, AppStatusId,
IF ( (AppStatusId = 80),"1","2" ) as res 
#(here i need res as "1" if AppStatusId = 80 for first 100 rows  )
FROM App
WHERE
AppStatusId = 80
or 
AppTypeId = 100
```

The query return 1000s of rows , I would like to get res column as 1 for first 100 rows with condition AppStatusId = 80. I am expecting following result

```
Id, AppStatusId,res
14343  ,80 ,    ,1
2234   ,80 ,    ,1
3232   ,80 ,    ,1
..................
..................
..................
..................
8975,  80,      ,1 # 100th row
3232,  80,      ,0
102,   80,      ,0
103,   80,      ,0
..................
..................
222,   55,      ,0 ( becuase of  or AppTypeId = 100 in where condition)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Id
    ,AppStatusId
    ,if(AppStatusId = 80 AND RowNumber <= 100, 1, 0) as res
FROM
    (
       SELECT
          *
          ,(@rn:= if(AppStatusId = 80, @rn + 1,@rn)) as RowNumber
       FROM
          App a
          CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0) var
       WHERE
          a.AppStatusId = 80
          OR a.AppTypeId = 100
       ORDER BY
          Id, AppstatusId...., whatever you want for the first 100 records
    ) t
```

This should get you there.  It generates a row number that increments only when `AppStatusId = 80` plus it will allow you to pick any order of the records so the first 100 records where `AppStatusId = 80` do not have to be consecutive if you don't want them to be.  If you do simply order as such and it will still work.

Comment: remember you have to alias the subquery ;)

Comment: this too `CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0)`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza duh yes thanks caught while you were typing.  Thanks!

Comment: Im not sure, but I think `RowNumber <= 100` should be `RowNumber <= AppTypeId ` but that is for OP.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza using AppTypeId wouldn't get the "first 100 rows".  Actually depending on the recordset it would be an unknown number of rows because AppTypeId can be assumably any integer as long as AppStatusId = 80, so that could get 5 rows , 100, 60....etc.

Comment: I tought that 100 was a variable or something. But if that is hardcode no need any change.